# What's the deal with this eagle?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is the view from the top of the tower just east of Bleak Falls Barrow. There's an eagle's nest, and an eagle that visits it. Climbing up and touching the nest has no effect, but shooting the eagle causes the nest to disappear.

Is the eagle there for a reason? Does shooting it have any effect?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eagles are more than scenery in Skyrim. If you shoot them down with spells or a bow you can harvest their feathers and beak for alchemical purposes. But that is all.

Comment: *Finding* their drops on a mountainside is an entirely different story, but otherwise it's that simple, yeah. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Makes me really miss featherfall and levitate. And Mark/Recall for that matter.

Comment: Note: technically it is a hawk, NOT an eagle.

Answer (score 7):

You can also ride on their backs if you climb up to their nest and jump on when they land. It's cool to be flown around, but also very hard to stay on for long though! A well-timed Become Ethereal shout is the only thing likely to prevent gravitational death if you decide to take up hawk surfing.

Comment: As stupid as this sounds, it might actually be possible. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mvhy3RLv3kU (It is a bug of course).

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://paintfag.deviantart.com/art/Scyther-can-not-learn-Fly-161658836

Comment: @Ids Your video link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Well, that makes me sad. I can't recall the contents. Here have a video of a person riding an eagle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp8dYNmFmfU